# ios how to get internet data from 3g and application specific data from Wifi

Tags: iphone, ios4, annotations, mkmapview, 3g-network

Question community. I am currently doing this application where I would like to record a position on the mapview based a coordinate point which is constantly being updated by a server application. The server application sends out this information using wifi and I can see that I am updating the position of my an annotation as the data comes in. The problem comes up when I try to zoom into the mapview, it seems to get pixelated. I did some trials runs and it turns out that for some reason the iphone does not update the tiles of the mapview because it is trying to get the data from the wifi connection as opposed to the 3g connection.

My question, how (if possible) do I force the mapview to get it's tile updates from the 3g connection. I am aware that I could go the "offline maps" route, however I would just like to see if this can be done.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: So, did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you testing within a closed network where your wifi connection does not reach the outside world? Why can your wifi connection not reach the map tiles? Are you talking about Google tiles? If so then speak to your network admin and ask if you need your proxies to be set up. Basically this is not something that needs to be fixed in your code, it's a network issue. The iPhone will use whatever network it can find to get the info it needs, you need to make sure the networks it finds have internet access.